# Trying to switch specific UILabel text in list

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a list of data coming from a database and one of the columns is a date field.  Inside that date field I have the date and time.  To save room, I have a tap feature to switch between the date and time each time the user touches that uilabel.  My issue is trying to know which uilabel the user touched.  I have each uilabel with it's own tag incrementing by 1, but I'm confused on how to tell my function which label got pressed.

This is inside a for loop:

```
_short_time = [date substringFromIndex:range.location + 2];
_short_date = [date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
_dateSwitch = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 9, 75, 20)];
_dateSwitch.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
_dateSwitch.text = _short_date;
_dateSwitch.tag = i + 1;
_dateSwitch.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[_dateSwitch setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
UITapGestureRecognizer *gSwap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(switchDateTime:)];
```

This is the function being called "switchDateTime":

```
- (void) switchDateTime: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    if (state == 1) {
        if (_dateSwitch.tag == _fId) {
            [_dateSwitch setText:_short_date];
            state = FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        [_dateSwitch setText:_short_time];
        state = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a negative number for my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your gesture recognizer on your label like this:

```
[_dateSwitch addGestureRecognizer:gSwap];
```

Then on your method to identify which view the gesture recognizer is attached to:

```
UILabel *tappedLabel = (UILabel *)sender.view;
```

Comment: As you can see from the OP's code, the "sender" is the tap gesture, not the label. You can't simply cast the tap gesture to a label and expect it to work.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question which is how to tell which label got tapped.

Comment: @jeraldo, I'm actually doing that down below in my for loop:

Comment: Try my latest edit. You can now get the tag of your UILabel when casted from the gestureRecognizer's view. UILabel *tappedLabel = (UILabel *)sender.view; then NSLog(@"this %li",(long)tappedLabel.tag); to see if your getting the correct label.

Comment: That worked awesomely.  Thanks.  I've got one more issue on this though, but will create another question about it.